# Not able to inject a bean into a non-spring bean

Tags: spring, autowired

There is a scenario, where I need to inject one class into a non-spring bean class.

```
public class ProducerTask implements Runnable {                 --> This is not a component

     @Override
     public void run() {
          BBExecutor bbExecutor = new BBExecutor (codes);
                    bbExecutor .process(details);
     }

}
```

And then my class is BBExecutor

```
public class BBExecutor {    --> Since this class is used in the thread, it can't be injected using Autowired, because we used "New" keyword.

     @Autowired
     BBService bbService --> This is coming as null

}
```

Note: BBService is defined as a component.
How can I get this bbService object

Comment: Either do an ugly lookup or make those things components/beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum, For a thread, I can't annotate it as a component.

Comment: who creates ProducerTask? a spring component or not?

Comment: ... and what is "codes" used in constructor of BBExecutor? Where does it come from?

Comment: a `Runnable` isn't a thread, it is a simple component. You can create a prototype to it, add the additional properties you need and supply it to a `TaskExecutor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that's not a good idea to inject beans into classes that are not handled by the Spring context. Do you really have some concerns about making this class manageable by Spring?

Of course, there is a way to get any existing bean from the context but I do not recommend to do that in your situation. Try to think about the overall architecture of your application. Usually, such situation are about some basic mistakes in it.

Or maybe this way. I suppose `ProducerTask` is created by some Spring bean.

```
public class ProducerTask implements Runnable {                 --> This is not a component

    private BBService bbService;

    public ProducerTask(BBService bbService) {
        this.bbService = bbService;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
         BBExecutor bbExecutor = new BBExecutor (codes, bbService);
                bbExecutor .process(details);
    }
}


public class BBExecutor {    --> Since this class is used in the thread, it can't be injected using Autowired, because we used "New" keyword.

     private BBService bbService; 

     public BBExecutor(some parameters...., BBService bbService) {
         this.bbService = bbService;
     }

}
```

Comment: Alexey, yes, the thread is a defined one and shouldn't be annotated and can't be modified. But the method  of a class, needs to be executing one of the method from a service.

Comment: Another way is to inject the service into the component which is creating `ProducerTask` and pass the instance of service into the constructor of ProducerTask as a parameter. And pass it into all other classes this way. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Gotcha! You are asking me to inject the service into the bean, pass it to the ProducerTask as a constructor autowiring and then use it. Am I right

Comment: Something like that. Autowire it into the bean which is creating your not bean classes and pass it through the constructor.